# The communication complexity of non-equality

Tags: algorithms, nondeterminism, communication-complexity

I'm familiar with the fooling set technique to obtain lower bounds for communication complexity protocols. The most basic example is the equality function for which the [diagonal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_complexity#Example:_EQ) gives the fooling set of size $2^n$, because each 1-output needs to be in its own monochromatic rectangle. Also, a similar property seems to be true when looking at 0-outputs: If we have a cover of the 0-outputs by a set of monochromatic rectangles, then no rectangle can contain **all** 0-outputs of 2 (or more) rows. This implies that we get the same complexity for the NEQ (non-equality) problem.

However, I read that for non-deterministic algorithms, the complexity of NEQ is only $O(\log n)$. This is because we simply need to "guess" an index $i$ where the inputs of Alice and Bob differ, which takes $\log n$ bits and then use $1$ additional bit to encode if $i=0$ or $i=1$.

But the complexity of such a non-deterministic algorithms is lower-bounded by the log of the size of the smallest cover of the $0$-outputs, which would still be $\log(2^n)=n$ (by the above argument that each row in the matrix accounts for at least one rectangle in the cover).

Obviously, I'm missing something here, but I haven't figured out what it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The protocol gives you a covering of the zeroes using $2n$ rectangles $R_{i,b} = X_{i,b} \times Y_{i,1-b}$, where $X_{i,b}$ (or $Y_{i,b}$) is the set of words whose $i$th bit equals $b$.